# new in hadoop: how can I use gson library in hadoop for mapreduce processing?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, gson

how can I use gson library in hadoop for mapreduce processing?
I use hadoop 2.3.0 in windows without any maven or Cygwin?
thanks all

Comment: Hive and Pig have ways to read JSON already

Comment: I SHOULD USE HIVE OR PIG TO USE GSON LIBRARY?

Comment: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform?msg=5277760#xx5277760xx) in this link they use gson library but I don't understand where is the jar files?

Comment: Chill out with the caps lock, please. No one wants to help if you are shouting. The jar files are typically in HDFS, but you can also bundle them in the map reduce program (though, I don't know anyone that actually writes mapreduce code by hand any more)

Comment: I'm really sorry for typing with caps lock. it's not on purpose. thanks a lot for your help. excuse me. how can I fine HDFS folder in my pc?

Comment: HDFS is part of Hadoop. It is not a folder on your computer. It's a distributed file system that you (most frequently) interact with through the command line. Step 1) I suggest you learn more about the Hadoop ecosystem first